# How can I fix FileNotFoundException for embedded fonts (Java)?

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, embedded-resource, filenotfoundexception

I have used some embedded fonts in my project. here is the code used in the main class of the project :

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final Font myEmbeddeFont = Font.loadFont(new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/myEmbeddeFont.ttf")), 14);
        final Font myEmbeddeFont2 = Font.loadFont(new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/myEmbeddeFont2.TTF")), 14);

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/main/HomeScreen.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage = stage;
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMinWidth(700);
        stage.setMinHeight(600);

        stage.show();


    }
}
```

When I run the project intellij de, it works fine. But after I export the project, the extracted jar file won't run. When I open the jar file using command prompt, it shows this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\myEmbeddeFont.ttf (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at main.Main.start(Main.java:28)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application main.Main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be causing the exception is loading fonts with File class, designed for accessing files in filesystem, not in .jar archive.
Simple solution would be to use [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to obtain InputStream, and use InputStream to load the font. Font.loadFont() method accepts any InputStream, so it should work seamlessly.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) for reference.

The following code should do the job:

```java
final Font myEmbeddeFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myEmbeddeFont.ttf"), 14);
```

Comment: Since the class seems to be part of the `main` package and in the path `main` does not seem the directory containing the font, it would be better to specify the full path starting at tehe classpath root (`/main/resources/myEmbeddeFont.ttf` or `/resources/myEmbeddeFont.ttf` or possibly `/myEmbeddeFont.ttf`).

Comment: I used ```final Font myEmbeddeFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/ImyEmbeddeFont.ttf"), 14);``` it works fine but the method is case-sensitive.Thank you for your help.